# MySQL how to use SET type to select records where a SET contains one or more items from another SET

Tags: mysql, set

I have a table called 'recipes' that lists, in a SET type called 'ingredients', all of the foods used in a recipe (recipes are restricted to using a small number of specific ingredients).

**recipes table**

id (int)

recipeName (text)

ingredients (SET)

I have another table called 'food_types'. Each record has a 'name' field (e.g. 'fruit', 'poultry', 'spices', 'meat', ...) and a SET type called 'items' that holds the ingredients belonging to that food type. E.g. for the 'fruit' record the SET might be 'apple,orange,pear,banana'.
'

**food_types table**

id (int)

category (text)

items (SET)

My problem is how to create a MySQL query that selects all records from the 'recipes' table that has one or more item from the given 'items' set in the 'ingredients' set.

So in English my query might be:

'Select all recipes where the ingredients contains one or more fruit'

Can anyone suggest a good way to do this with a MySQL query?

NOTE: I appreciate that there are better ways to structure the tables for a recipes/ingredients problem but I am looking for a MySQL query solution that does this with SETs and the tables described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inappropriate use of a SET field - you can't add a food_type without having to do a schema modification, always a good indicator that your structure is wrong. Use a join table to represent a many:many relationship. In this case, create a table `ingredient_type` that refers to both tables with `ingredient_id` and `food_type_id`. This also allows you to have ingredients with multiple types, like a SET does, but much more flexible.

```
ingredient (ingredient):
apple
orange
chicken
ginger
potato

food_type (type):
fruit
vegetable
meat
poultry
spice

ingredient_type (ingredient, type)
apple, fruit
orange, fruit
chicken, meat
chicken, poultry
ginger, vegetable
ginger, spice
potato, vegetable

recipe_ingredient (recipe, ingredient):
recipe1, chicken
recipe1, potato
recipe2, orange
recipe2, ginger
```

With that structure, you can do queries like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(recipe) FROM recipe_ingredient WHERE ingredient = 'orange';
```

That will show you all recipes that use oranges. Slightly more complex:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(recipe) FROM recipe_ingredient JOIN ingredient_type on recipe_ingredient.ingredient = ingredient_type.ingredient WHERE ingredient_type.type = 'fruit';
```

That will find all recipes that use any ingredient that is a fruit.

**EDIT: On using SETs.**

You can do this by making use of the binary nature of SET storage. Where there is an overlap between recipe ingredients and category members, the number of set bits in a bitwise AND (using the `&` operator) will be > 0:

```
SELECT DISTINCT recipeName FROM recipes JOIN food_types ON BIT_COUNT(food_types.items & recipes.ingredients) > 0 WHERE food_types.category = 'fruit';
```

This will only work if the ingredients and items set definitions are absolutely identical.

There are other problems with SETs:

- they can only contain up to 64 items
- field values are always in the same order as the set
- most queries other than simple matches (for example to match on a single item within a set) are not indexed
- unless definitions are identical, SETs can't be compared
- There is nowhere to put additional metadata about each item

This approach defeats most of the point of using a relational database. This is textbook first-normal-form database stuff. The only purpose I can see for a structure like this is to use as an example of how not to do it.

Comment: I agree that that is a much better way of implementing what I have described but my example database was a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve expressed in terms of food stuffs rather than the real items I am using. In my case, for example, the ingredients can belong to more than one food type. I am still looking for a way to do what I am after using SETs and the two tables I describe.

Comment: Ingredients can belong to more than one type in my example - look at ginger and chicken. You really don't want to use SETs for this.

Comment: Ok, I agree that your answer is a better solution for the ingredients/recipe problem but I am stuck with my structure for my real life problem. Is it possible to create a query using my tables and my sets that does what I want?

Comment: The ingredients and items sets are identical in my application. Your query works perfectly. None of the problems with SETs that you mention are problems for me so I think the SET solution is not wholly inappropriate. Many thanks for your solution.